# Identify cluster of circular growths on tree branch

Tags: identification

Can anyone help me identify this?

[image: Photo of object attached to tree branch]

This was found on a tree branch in the Midwestern United States. What is it? Is it harmful in any way?

Answer (score 7):

After some searching, I've positively identified this myself as the eggs of a wheel bug ([Arilus cristatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arilus_cristatus)).

[image: Wheel bug photo]

Here's what Wikipedia has to say about their egg laying:

> After mating, the female will lay 40 to 200 small, brown, cylindrical eggs, and eventually die. Females lay eggs on trees, bushes, twigs, and other objects. Secreted glue serves as an adhesive which maintains the cluster formation of the eggs.

And here is a photo from Wikipedia showing their eggs with nymphs present:

[image: Wheel bug eggs]

From what I can tell, this is nothing to be concerned about. These insects feed on many pests and are generally considered beneficial.

Comment: Cheese and crackers! That looks like something out of the TV show Stargate!